# ADO.Net Entity Framework generate model from XSD file

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, xsd-validation

I have a rather large XSD file and I have heard that it is possible using the entity framework to connect to XML files like databases and validate them against the XSD, however I do not know how to go about doing this.

So what I'm trying to do is generate a entity framework model from my XSD file, and I imagine this will generate a series of objects which will be used when opening a XML file for validation and population.

Comment: Note that not all XML schemas will map to the relational model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq2xsd will do that. http://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/ once dead it now lives on codeplex.

Comment: I haven't kept up on it but I used the alpha version before it was open source and never had any problems.  The version on codeplex is ready for 4.0.  It's open source so that's nice too.

Answer (score 1):

As well you can try to use latest (4.5) version of [XML Schema Definition Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx)

```
xsd.exe /d /eld "your_schema.xsd"
```

where `/eld` option enable you to use [LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399401.aspx)