# xml dtd -> sql schema

Tags: sql, xml, dtd

I've got xml document and XML's DTD.

Is there any tool that makes possible to:

1. create full sql schema from DTD.
2. convert XML doc with data into SQL.

Comment: No such tool, as XML is too free flowing to allow translation to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

DTD is a deprecated technology. You'll need to convert it to XSD to have any real hope of achieving this. W3 has [A Conversion Tool from DTD to XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/2000/04/schema_hack/) which might help.

I'm thinking that you may be able to use the Codeplex project mentioned in the [ADO.Net Entity Framework generate model from XSD file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546015/ado-net-entity-framework-generate-model-from-xsd-file) question to generate an Entity Framework model, retarget the model to a database and then generate schema from that.

Bear in mind, that I have not tried this myself. It just seems a likely path. I hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following tools:

> 1) create full sql schema from DTD.

- [DTDParse](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SGML-DTDParse/bin/dtdparse) + [XML::RDB](http://search.cpan.org/~metzzo/XML-RDB/RDB.pm)

> 2) convert XML doc with data into SQL.

- [Transform XML using XSLT to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121456/transform-xml-using-xslt-to-sql)

**References**

- [DTD Tools](http://www.xmlpitstop.com/ListTools/DispContentType/DTD/PageNumber/1.aspx)
- [XML Matters: Using Python modules xml2sql and dtd2sql](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-matters12.html)